# running calculation in separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm trying to run a calculation in a new thread, I'm just not sure the correct way to do it. I'm not sure if I should use:

```
private Thread calcThread = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        calc();
    }
};
```

and then use calcThread.run() when I want to do the calculation or if I should do:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      calc();
    }
  }).start();
```

whenever I want to run my calculation.

Which is preferable, if either?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this

```
public class cal extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        calc();
    }
}
```

Just by creating object of this class like this

```
cal c = new cal();
c.start();
```

you can start your thread performing calculation wherever you want in the code.

Comment: I'll go ahead and choose this as my answer. I had to add a handler to update my UI. I also had to use .run() instead of .start() because it gets called multiple times. It seems to be working now. Thanks.

Comment: If you are choosing this as your answer, make sure to mark Rockers' answer as the accepted answer so he gets credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to most things on a background thread in Android is an AsyncTask.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

AsyncTask will handle running your calculation on a background thread and will then return your results on the UI thread.

```
   private class DoCalculationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        calc();
        return null;
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Post results to main thread
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same. The second is slightly cleaner, IMHO, since implementing interfaces is widely considered a better practice than subclassing framework classes. What if in some distant future `Thread.run()` is not the thread entry point anymore? Unlikely, I know...